# Wix Burn automatically cancelling

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.10

I have a very simple Burn bootstrapper that installs the Visual Studio 2015 Redistributable and then runs our application installer (created with Wix). During installation, after installing the redistributable, a dialog pops up automatically that asks if I would like to cancel (i.e., the same thing that would happen if I clicked the Cancel button).

I've created several other installers that use this same pattern and never have seen this problem.  Below is the simplified installer with some identifying information removed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
<?define ProductVersion = "1.0"?>
<?define Manufacturer = "XXXX, Inc."?>

<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
    <?define VCRedistExe = "vc_redist.x64.exe"?>
<?else?>
    <?define VCRedistExe = "vc_redist.x86.exe"?>
<?endif?>

<Bundle Name="$(var.ProductName)" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" Condition="VersionNT >= v6.0">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="$(var.AssetsPath)\License.rtf" SuppressOptionsUI="yes"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="redist"/>

        <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.MsiPath)" DisplayInternalUI="no"/>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>

<Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="redist_vc140">
        <ExePackage Id="vc140" DisplayName="Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable" Cache="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" SourceFile="resources/$(var.VCRedistExe)" InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart" Protocol="burn">
            <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot"/>

            <!-- Ignore "Newer version installed" error -->
            <ExitCode Value="1638" Behavior="success"/>
        </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="redist">
        <PackageGroupRef Id="redist_vc140"/>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should remove the following exit code, as it is not necessary for installing your packages. Possibly conflicting with your bootstrapper installation.

```
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot"/>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Handling ExitCode 1638 is necessary in case the user has a new version of the redistributable installed on their machine.  I don't know exactly why we are handling 3010 - it's pulled from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396773/wix-burn-vcredist

Comment: Removing the handling for error 3010 fixes it - I will need to do some more research and see what the reason was for that.  Marking this as the answer although we do need to keep ExitCode 1638.